# Vert.x Oauth 2 Authorization server

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, vert.x

Can some one help me to setup Oauth 2 Authorisation server Vert.x (3.3.0).I dont find any documentation related to it. 
I found vertx-auth-oauth2 this vert.x module but I guess it will be useful if Authorisation server is different
 e.g

The following code snippet is from vert.x documentation

```
  OAuth2Auth oauth2 = OAuth2Auth.create(vertx, OAuth2FlowType.AUTH_CODE, new OAuth2ClientOptions()
        .setClientID("YOUR_CLIENT_ID")
        .setClientSecret("YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET")
        .setSite("https://github.com/login")
        .setTokenPath("/oauth/access_token")
        .setAuthorizationPath("/oauth/authorize")
);

// when there is a need to access a protected resource or call a protected method,
// call the authZ url for a challenge

String authorization_uri = oauth2.authorizeURL(new JsonObject()
    .put("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8080/callback")
    .put("scope", "notifications")
    .put("state", "3(#0/!~"));

// when working with web application use the above string as a redirect url

// in this case GitHub will call you back in the callback uri one should now complete the handshake as:


String code = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // the code is provided as a url parameter by github callback call

oauth2.getToken(new JsonObject().put("code", code).put("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8080/callback"), res -> {
  if (res.failed()) {
    // error, the code provided is not valid
  } else {
    // save the token and continue...
  }
});
```

It is using Github as Authorisation server.I am curious to know how to implement Authorisation server in vert.x ,i know spring security provides this feature i.e Oauth2Server and OAuth2Client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vert.x OAuth2 is just a OAuth2Client, there is no server implementation so you cannot get it from the Vert.x Project itself.

Vert.x OAuth2 supports the following flows:

- Authorization Code Flow (for apps with servers that can store persistent information).
- Password Credentials Flow (when previous flow can’t be used or during development).
- Client Credentials Flow (the client can request an access token using only its client credentials)

Comment: Do you know if the Implicit Flow will be supported in the future?

Comment: You could ask for it to be implemented on the issue tracker. Then depending on the roadmap and resources or community pull requests it might be in.